# PHPMyAdmin login with different ip

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to login to my phpmyadmin portal with an account created under a certain ip and not localhost. How can i allow that? I have already changed my config file to look like this.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '149.102.148.225';
```

And that does not seem to work.

Comment: I'd switch that list to `127.0.0.1` and connect to the host via ssh tunnel instead of direct, unless you want to try your luck, then you can switch it to `0.0.0.0` and then there is no IP restriction anymore (not best practice, nor recommended way)..

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Still triggers this same error when logging in.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pterodactyluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: make sure your username has correct host in mysql.user that matches your password and privs as well.

Comment: the issue is its trying to login at the localhost ip not 127.0.0.1 which is what the user is created under